# Angular SSR sever side render page still call client side javascript rendering and kill page performace

Tags: angular

We have developed a web app using angular 7. We noticed our google page insight score for desktop n mobile is very poor when angular render page from client side. So we used angular universal to render pages from server side. We got the good improvement in FCP & FMP. But did not see improvement in other elements as we noticed client side still javascript execution happens which is already done from server side. If we stop rendering from  client side, google page insight score for desktop shows 100. But then user can not click any button rendered by server side execution.

How do we stop duplicate rendering at client side and achieve good score from google insight?